# Getting Bonding Status in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos7

In CentOS 6 I had my trusty /proc/net/bonding/bond0 that would give me the following information:

```
[kbrandt@ny-tsdb01: ~] cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 2
    Actor Key: 33
    Partner Key: 33116
    Partner Mac Address: 00:23:04:ee:be:01

Slave Interface: em1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: ec:f4:bb:c2:14:68
Aggregator ID: 1
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: em2
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: ec:f4:bb:c2:14:6a
Aggregator ID: 1
Slave queue ID: 0
```

/proc/net/bonding is not present in CentOS 7, where do I find this information my teams in CentOS 7?

Comment: In CentOS 7, the bonding module is not loaded by default. Enter the following command as root user to enable it. "modprobe --first-time bonding", else if just viewing, a cat /proc/net/bonding/bondX

Comment: But I have active teams, so what is doing the teaming currently? I am wary of loading a module if something else is doing its role?

Comment: It probably involves systemd *somehow*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where "teaming" and "bonding" used to be used interchangeably, starting in RHEL 7, they are two completely different things. Both perform the same link aggregation and redundancy/failover functions, [but they do so in different ways](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/06/23/team-driver/). If you have a `team0` interface instead of the usual `bond0` interface, you can get status for the team with the [`teamdctl team0 state view`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Controlling_teamd_with_teamdctl.html) command.